# runtime error 9 message subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create my first VBA code to basically:
-select a cell
-sort the column by A-Z
-pivot the data
-create a line chart
-re-size the chart to make it bigger

I'm getting a runtime error 9 message `subscript out of range` and it highlights the following line
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("advertiserConversionReport_3045").Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear

What I did was to open another workbook and tried to run the macro on the data.
Looking through the code (I'm not a developer) I'm seeing that the errors could be the reference to the initial workbook `advertiserConversionReport_3045` and perhaps a previously set range for the pivot `Range("A2:F97")`

```
Sub ActionReport()
'
' ActionReport Macro
' This macro will pivot data from the action report and create a line chart to show     trending of credited conversions by day.
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+shift+a
'
Range("B1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("advertiserConversionReport_3045").Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("advertiserConversionReport_3045").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("advertiserConversionReport_3045").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:F97")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "advertiserConversionReport_3045!R1C1:R97C6", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14) _
    .CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1" _
    , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Day")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Conversion Action")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Credited Conversions"), _
    "Sum of Credited Conversions", xlSum
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Conversion Action")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$3:$R$11")
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 1.6583333333, msoFalse, _
    msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleHeight 1.7065974045, msoFalse, _
    msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-24
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft -38.25
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop -81.75
End Sub`
```

Does anyone know how to fix this and execute the macro successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because the "Activeworkbook" doesn't have the sheet called "advertiserConversionReport_3045".

Avoid using ActiveWorkbook. Create Objects and then work with them. You may want to see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179)

Try something like this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim thiswb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook

    Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook

    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xlsm")

    With wbNew
        .Worksheets("advertiserConversionReport_3045").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: hey siddharth, i'm still quite unsure as to how to fix the code.. if I were to include C:\Sample.xlsm and "advertiserConversionReport_3045" into the code, wouldn't it revert back to the same error?

Comment: Where is the sub `ActionReport()`? And where is the sheet `advertiserConversionReport_3045`? EDIT: `C:\Sample.xlsm` is an example. As mentioned in the post, you will have to amend it

Comment: mmm still pretty unsure as to how to go about doing it. by the way, the set ranges in the code would also give me more problems right?

Comment: You haven't answered my questions :)

Comment: mmm really sorry about that. i'm trying hard to understand the code myself, given that I have no knowledge about coding..

sub ActionReport() I have no idea where it is..

while the advertiserConversionReport_3045 is a file stored as .xlms on the desktop

Comment: Hmmm, now you have got me confused :) `advertiserConversionReport_3045` is the file name or the sheet name? Did you not write this code?

Comment: mmm i didn't write the code. i used the macro recording tool. and i think you're right .. advertiserConversionReport_3045 is the sheet name. sorry

Comment: So now what you have to do is replace `"C:\Sample.xlsm"` with the file which has your data. Does this file have the sheet `advertiserConversionReport_3045`?

Comment: hi Siddharth, the new file would have a new sheet name. is it possible to use just a generic 'activeworkbook' 'activesheet' kind of function?

Comment: I've actually solved it - referring to http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/45119-rename-active-sheet-without-specifiying-name.html

the solution would be to use ActiveSheet.Name = "my_new_name" at the start of the code so the code has a generic run for different workbooks having different sheet names.

thanks siddharth for your help